# URL and readbuffer won't export

Tags: java

I have a huge program that I have spent 100+ hours on. It would not work when I exported it even though it worked fine in Ecipse. I made a smaller program with just that code to test it out. I have searched and changed my code and I still can't get my program to work when I export and run my jar file. It works great in Eclipse.  I have tried file reader, stream, buffer, standing on my head, and changed to anything I have seen online about reading a file that is included in the jar file. I am new to coding so some things still confuse me. I changed the .java to .zip and looked at the pieces and the file is in there.

My read code is

```
private void readFile(){
    try {
        System.out.println("starting array");       
        String[] myarray;  
        myarray = new String[5];  
        System.out.println("myarray"+myarray);  
        url = getClass().getResource("classifyinginfo.txt"); 
        System.out.println("url is "+url);
        readbuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(url.getPath()));          
        line1 = readbuffer.readLine();
        line1 = readbuffer.readLine();                  
        line1 = readbuffer.readLine();                  
        line1 = readbuffer.readLine();                                      
        { String splitarray[] = line1.split(",");
            firstentry = splitarray[0];
            myarray[0]=splitarray[3];
            myarray[1]=splitarray[4];
            myarray[2]=splitarray[5];
            myarray[3]=splitarray[6];
            myarray[4]=splitarray[7]; 

            //line2 and 3 readbuffer etc

            Arrays.sort(myarray);
            for(int i=0; i < myarray.length; i++){
                System.out.println(myarray[i]);

                textArea.append(myarray[i]+"\n");}
        }       


        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myarray)); 
        //  textArea.setText(Arrays.toString(myarray));


        readbuffer.close(); } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("we have an error");}           
    System.out.println("Line: " + line1 );
}
```

please please tell me how to make this work in and out of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do like this:

```
url = getClass().getResource("classifyinginfo.txt"); 
readbuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));          
line1 = readbuffer.readLine();
```

The `FileReader` class can read individual files on disk, and that's all. But you don't need to use it once you have a URL. Modified in this way, the program will work whether the file is in a jar or not.

You can actually eliminate the URL altogether and just do this:

```
readbuffer =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("classifyinginfo.txt")));          
line1 = readbuffer.readLine();
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I guess that is what I need to fix on the other program. I should have asked hours ago. But then I wouldn't have learned as much.

Comment: I guess I have the same problem with my file line count. I have 'public int count(String filename) throws IOException {
   
  InputStream pt = new BufferedInputStream(new     FileInputStream(url.getPath()));'  ...I call it with 'count(url.getPath());' I tried open stream and get as resource. Any ideas?

Comment: SOunds like you should be able to solve it the same way, why can't you?

Comment: one is InputStream and other is ReadBuffer. I tried the same openStream and getResourceAsStream and changed it to ReadBuffer it still threw errors and won't go get the file once exported.

Comment: You would use just use "new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream())" if the file is part of your application. But if it's being "exported", then it's probably not part of your app that's accessible along the class path, and in that case you *must* use FileInputStream or FileReader.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I changed to url.openStream() as mentioned above, but how do I call it.I had count(url.getPath()) and changed it to count(url.openStream()) and it said I needed to change the method from count(String) to count(InputStream) when I did that it doesn't work outside of eclipse.

Comment: SO the problem really was the file counting in the first place. I cheated and hardcoded the file since it will stay the same anyway. Thanks again for helping those of us that know just enough to get ourselves in trouble.